# SQL Group By and Having clause and exists clause

Tags: sql, join, group-by, having, having-clause

These queries fetch records from multiple tables(AspNetUsers,AspNetUserRoles & AspNetRoles). The records will include only those **users which have multiple Roles.**
I am looking for reasons why 1st query works and the latter did not. Any help would be appreciated.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    U.Id,
    U.UserName
    ,R.Id
    ,R.Name AS RoleName
FROM AspNetUsers  AS U
JOIN AspNetUserRoles UR
    ON U.Id  = UR.UserId
JOIN AspNetRoles AS R
    ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT UserId,
            COUNT() AS NumberofRoles
            FROM AspNetUserRoles
            GROUP BY UserId
            HAVING COUNT() > 1)
```

**Query 2:(Only work if I remove R.Id & R.Name Otherwise it is not working)**

```
SELECT 
    U.Id,
    U.UserName
    ,R.Id
    ,R.Name AS RoleName
FROM AspNetUsers  AS U
JOIN AspNetUserRoles UR
    ON U.Id  = UR.UserId
JOIN AspNetRoles AS R
    ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
GROUP BY U.Id,U.UserName
```

The table diagram is attached for better clarity.
[image]

Comment: In your second query, the `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` columns are not consistent.  The query should be returning a compile error.

Comment: just read about GROUP BY and AGGREGATION Functions in SELECT

Comment: So in simple words, SELECT columns and GROUP BY columns should be the same?

Comment: The `EXISTS` needs a _correlated subquery_. I'd go with `IN (<subquery>)` here instead.

Comment: `SELECT 
 U.Id,
 U.UserName
 ,R.Id AS RoleID
 ,R.Name AS RoleName
FROM AspNetUsers  AS U
JOIN AspNetUserRoles UR
 ON U.Id  = UR.UserId
JOIN AspNetRoles AS R
 ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
WHERE U.Id IN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AspNetUserRoles GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`
This only returns records for one user. Why it is not returning records for all users having multiple roles

Answer (score 0):

The second query doesn't woek because you haven't defined anything known as R.

Comment: Please look again, (JOIN AspNetRoles AS R), R is defined

Comment: Yes, but you have to define it before the first join

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT 
    U.Id,
    U.UserName
    ,R.Id
    ,R.Name AS RoleName
FROM AspNetUsers  AS U
JOIN AspNetUserRoles UR
    ON U.Id  = UR.UserId
JOIN AspNetRoles AS R
    ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
GROUP BY U.Id,U.UserName,R.Id,R.Name
```

Comment: Yes, this is working. But this would return all the records. I am actually looking for only those records which have multiple Roles. Thank-you

Comment: can you provide sample data into table format in your question or sqlfiddle link whould be better  ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct way to fetch records that have multiple Roles.

```
SELECT 
    U.Id,
    U.UserName
    ,R.Id AS RoleID
    ,R.Name AS RoleName
FROM AspNetUsers  AS U
JOIN AspNetUserRoles UR
    ON U.Id  = UR.UserId
JOIN AspNetRoles AS R
    ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
WHERE U.Id IN (SELECT UserId FROM AspNetUserRoles GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```